# How to construct an array of objects? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

So I have a `class Star` which inherits another `class CelestialBody` . There's a third `class Planet` as well.

In my class Star in the private section I have an array of Planet objects `Planet* system` and an `int n` standing for the number of the planets.

Problem is - how do I construct it? I've tried this:

```
Star(char* newName, double newX, double newY, double newDiam, Planet* newSystem, int newN) : CelestialBody(newName, newX, newY, newDiam)
    {
        system = new Planet[newN];  
        system = newSystem;
        n = newN;
    }
```

but apparently it doesn't work...

Thanks for helping my out in advance!

Comment: Assigning two times in a row different values to `system` does not make much sense...

Comment: @WojtekSurowka Well... I went for the logic that I'm constructing with a char* which usually goes the following way: name = new char[strlen(newName) + 1]; name = newName;

Comment: "Usually"? Never not usually. What you think about I guess is `strcpy(name, newName)` instead of the second assignment.

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector` and forget about the pointers?

Comment: @WojtekSurowka strcpy(name, newName), yes, that's exactly what I meant. It's really late here, sorry. Can't believe I did so many mistakes in such a little time span. You get the point now, though. I hope...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Because it's a school assignment..

Comment: So you need to to something similar - but with memcpy instead of strcpy. Or better, as @PaulMcKenzie says, use vectors.

Comment: @user3213110 - `Because it's a school assignment` And how does that invalidate the usage of `vector`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie We are not allowed to use it..

Comment: @user3213110 So where do you issue a call to `delete`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In the class destructor.

Comment: @user3213110 So I can assume your class has a user defined copy constructor and assignment operator, or at least disabled these operations?  If not, then your program is faulty.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Of course it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This re-assignment is wrong:

```
system = new Planet[newSystem]; // <<== should be newN
system = newSystem;
```

you created an array, and then immediately "leaked" it. You can fix this by adding a loop, like this:

```
system = new Planet[newN]; 
for (int i = 0 ; i != newN ; i++) {
    system[i] = newSystem[i];
}
```

Although this would work, it is not the best solution: one reason is that your code needs to manage the `system[]` array, deleting it when you are done with the `Star`. C++ standard library offers much better choices.

For example, you could make your `system` an `std::vector<shared_ptr<Planet>>` - i.e. a vector of shared pointers to a `Planet`. The caller would pass you a container of planets (it could be a pointer and a count, in the way that you did, but it could also be a real C++ container).

Comment: It's for a school assignment.. And we haven't covered std::vector yet. Thanks for the answer, though. Works like a charm!

Comment: @user3213110 - `It's for a school assignment` The issue with this is that you're going to hand in an assignment that seems to work, possibly be graded an "A", but is riddled with bugs that you won't know exist.  That shouldn't be the goal of a C++ course (create buggy programs).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I completely get your point. My university is a little odd though. Out of 8 classes 1 is programming-related and the other 7 are Maths. I guess proper coding isn't a priority around here. Will definitely check out std::vector though.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Creating a buggy program may very well be the goal of an assignment, assuming that the instructor goes through all the bugs with the student, and shows how C++ library helps avoiding these bugs. Students often learn more from their mistakes than from their textbooks :-)